# Select x records after the minimum and max value within factor group(s)

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I have a dataset of daily temperature from different locations and different years. I would like to select the minimum value and then the records 90 days after this value for each location within each year. I would also like to selected the maximum value and the the records 90 days after this. I apologise, but I am not really sure how to easily provide a reproducible example given the cyclical nature of the data.

As an example, with the following data if I want to extract the rows from 3 days after the lowest and highest temp from each year:

```
date <- c ("1985-01-01", "1985-01-02", "1985-01-03", "1985-01-04", "1985-01-05", "1985-01-06", 
           "1985-01-07", "1985-01-08", "1985-01-09", "1985-01-10", "1985-01-11", "1985-01-12", "1985-01-13", "1985-01-14", "1985-01-15", 
           "1986-01-01", "1986-01-02", "1986-01-03", "1986-01-04", "1986-01-05", "1986-01-06", 
           "1986-01-07", "1986-01-08", "1986-01-09", "1986-01-10", "1986-01-11", "1986-01-12", "1986-01-13", "1986-01-14", "1986-01-15",
           "1987-01-01", "1987-01-02", "1987-01-03", "1987-01-04", "1987-01-05", "1987-01-06", 
           "1987-01-07", "1987-01-08", "1987-01-09", "1987-01-10", "1987-01-11", "1987-01-12", "1987-01-13", "1987-01-14", "1987-01-15")
year <- c(rep(1985, 15), rep(1986, 15), rep(1987, 15))
temp <- c(11, 10, 11, 9, 11, 12, 14, 16, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 8, 10, 11, 9, 11, 12, 14, 18, 17, 16, 19, 14, 13, 12, 11,
          11, 10, 11, 9, 11, 7, 14, 16, 17, 16, 15, 18, 17, 12, 11)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(date, year, temp))
```

Ideally the output would be in two different subsets, the first from the lowest each year:

```
dflow <- df[c(4:7, 16:19, 36:39), ]
```

The second from the highest value in each year:

```
dfhigh <- df[c(9:12, 26:29, 42:45),]
```

Clunky example sorry. Difference with this example data and my real data is the real data are each day of the year since 1985 and I want 90 records after the lowest and highest temp..

Comment: this shold be pretty straightforward, my approach would be using a `data.table` non-equi join... but I cannot provide an answer witout solid sample data and desired output... so please provide those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a tidyverse solution. In the absence of reproducible data, I have made some up that follow a cyclical pattern over a 3-year period:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), by = "1 day", length.out = 1096),
                 Temp = 52 - 20 * cos(1:1096 * 2 * pi/365) + rnorm(1096, 0, 5))
```

Note that I have all my dates stored as actual dates in my date column. From the look of your data, I would be a bit concerned that the dates are stored as strings and the years as numbers. If this is the case it would be best to do something like:

```r
df <- df %>% mutate(Date = strptime(paste(Date, Year), format = "%d-%b %Y"))
```

before doing the rest of this. It's far easier to work with dates and times if you store them as such in your data.

The trick here is to create two new columns: `post_min` and `post_max`, which we initially make zero everywhere except at the minimum temperature and maximum temperatures for each year. For each vector we subtract a length-90 lagged version of itself after ungrouping the data. The `cumsum` of the resulting columns will have 1s for the minimum/maximum temperatures and the 90 days after them for each year.

```
plot_df <- df %>% 
  mutate(Year = lubridate::year(Date)) %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  mutate(post_min = +(Temp == min(Temp)),
         post_max = +(Temp == max(Temp))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(post_min = cumsum(post_min - lag(post_min, 90, default = 0)),
         post_max = cumsum(post_max - lag(post_max, 90, default = 0)))
```

To show this works, let's plot the results:

```
  ggplot(plot_df, aes(Date, Temp)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = Date), plot_df %>% filter(post_min > 0),
             alpha = 0.1, colour = "blue") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = Date), plot_df %>% filter(post_max > 0),
             alpha = 0.1, colour = "red")
```

[image]

You will notice that the coldest day in 2018 occurred right at the end of the year, so the 90 days run into 2019. The coldest day in 2019 also occurred in December, so it runs into 2020. However, the coldest date in 2020 was in January, so the 90 days for 2019 and 2020 overlap. This may not be a problem with your actual data, but if it is, you may wish to consider grouping by e.g. October to October each year.

<sup>Created on 2020-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Actually, sorry, @Allan Cameron when I post this code straight into R, it actually only identifies one period for each of the min and the max - instead of multiple as is indicated in your figure. Seems like it is only going from the global min and max instead of within each year.

Comment: My apologies - it was because I had loaded plyr after dplyr (rookie maneuvers)....